# CSS layout issue divs with independent scrolls

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple layout, problem is with the overflow auto, the content div does scroll like I want, and everything is positioned where I want it also seams responsive as I adjust the screen size. Problem entire content div scrolls, despite having the other 3 divs set to overflow auto as well, What I want is for each div to be able to scroll independently of the others, all within the height and width of the content div.

[image: layout]

here is the link to the image in case it doesn't show up here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d0Nu.jpg

forgive the crude drawing but this is what I am trying to accomplish if even possible. Probably possible if I use iframes instead of div, but i am trying to avoid having to do a complicated ajax solution of passing data between iframes. Was hoping to do it with just divs.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
h2 {
text-align:center;
margin-top:3px;
margin-bottom:4px;
}
#content {
border-radius: 15px;
background-color:#999999;
border-style:groove;
border-color:#000000;
border-width:thick;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 62%;
height: 74%;
overflow:auto;
}
#lpanel {
float:left;
width: 66%;
padding:5px;
overflow:auto;
}
#prev {
padding:5px;
overflow:auto;
}
#info {
padding:5px;
overflow:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="lpanel">
            <h2>some content goes here</h2>
            <p>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content </p>            

            <p>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content </p>            

            <p>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content </p>            

            <p>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content </p>            

            <p>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content </p>            

            <p>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content </p>            

            <p>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content </p>            
        </div>
        <div id="rpanel">
            <div id="prev">
                <h2>some more content goes here</h2>
                <p> maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image
                 maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image
                  maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image </p>            
            </div>
            <div id="info">
                <h2>information or ads can go here</h2>
                <p>information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? </p>            

                <p>information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? </p>            

                <p>information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? </p>            

                <p>information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? </p>            

                <p>information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? </p>            

                <p>information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? 
                information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? </p>            

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>                      

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you need such a result? - https://ibb.co/NmngZmy

Comment: yes i do need such a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule `overflow: auto` requires **height**.

First, set `overflow: hidden` for selector `#content`. This will prevent the scrollbar from appearing for this selector.

Next, add this to your css by specifying the **height** for selector `#rpanel`. Like this:

```
#rpanel {
    height: 100%;
}
```

And set the **height** for each selector, inside `#rpanel`. Like this:

```
#prev {
    ...
    height: 35%;
}

#info {
    ...
    height: 65%;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

#content {
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #999999;
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-width: thick;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 62%;
    height: 74%;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
    overflow: hidden;
}

#lpanel {
    float: left;
    width: 66%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#rpanel {
    height: 100%;
}

#prev {
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 35%;
}

#info {
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 65%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="lpanel">
            <h2>some content goes here</h2>
            <p>
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content
            </p>

            <p>
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content
            </p>

            <p>
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content
            </p>

            <p>
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content
            </p>

            <p>
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content
            </p>

            <p>
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content
            </p>

            <p>
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="rpanel">
            <div id="prev">
                <h2>some more content goes here</h2>
                <p>
                    maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an
                    image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image
                    maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image maybe an image
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="info">
                <h2>information or ads can go here</h2>
                <p>
                    information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we
                    all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right?
                    information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we
                    all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right?
                    information ads, we all hate ads right?
                </p>

                <p>
                    information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we
                    all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right?
                    information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we
                    all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right?
                    information ads, we all hate ads right?
                </p>

                <p>
                    information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we
                    all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right?
                    information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we
                    all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right?
                    information ads, we all hate ads right?
                </p>

                <p>
                    information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we
                    all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right?
                    information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we
                    all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right?
                    information ads, we all hate ads right?
                </p>

                <p>
                    information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we
                    all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right?
                    information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we
                    all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right?
                    information ads, we all hate ads right?
                </p>

                <p>
                    information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we
                    all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right?
                    information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we
                    all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right? information ads, we all hate ads right?
                    information ads, we all hate ads right?
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set a height on the elements.   In order for overflow to have an effect, the block-level container must have either a set height (height or max-height) or white-space set to nowrap.

```
#lpanel {
    float: left;
    width: 66%;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100vh;
}
#prev {
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 25vh;
}
#info {
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 75vh;
}
```